# How to Create Incoming Connections in c#

Tags: c#

How to create an incoming connection(Dial-In) programatically in c# or vc++ or any language in windows OS,
we can create it manually by clicking Start Menu----> MyNetwrok places----->Select View Network connection----> Create New connection ----->select setup advanced connection---->Click Next---->Select Accept incoming connection---Click next and select the modem.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [RasAPI32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545679(v=VS.85).aspx).
More details and sample you can also find [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c2c1a26a-61b2-4b52-b6dc-c3a3efa5ceb6) and [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/ca454998-74ad-4637-a6fe-ff120699795e/).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for giving quick reply. do u have any sample code  that satisfy above requirement using RasAPI32.

Comment: There is a sample here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c2c1a26a-61b2-4b52-b6dc-c3a3efa5ceb6. 
I think you can adopt it for your needs. Also please check in MSDN there must be something, but most probably in unmanaged code.